# Pynput keyboard listener not working on Macbook air M2

Tags: python, macos, pynput

I have recently purchased a Macbook air M2. One python code that I have been successfully been using on my older Macbook air, doesn't longer work for some reason.

I receive this error message when trying to run the code in Spyder 5.3.3 through Anaconda, despite adding accessibility to Anaconda via System preferences:

> This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.

When trying to run the code via terminal I receive the following error:

> zsh: segmentation fault ...

OS: MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

There shouldn't be problems with the code, but it seems there is some problem adding the correct accessibility? Does pynput not work on the latest Macbooks or is there some other reason to it not working?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyperclip
import os
import os.path
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from striprtf import striprtf
import re


def replace_words(string, dictionary):
    # sort keys by length, in reverse order
    for item in sorted(dictionary.keys(), key = len, reverse = True):
        string = re.sub(item, dictionary[item], string)
    return string


SAVE_FILE = input("Name of clipboard file: ")

save_path = "/Users/username/Clipboard"
FileName = os.path.join(save_path, SAVE_FILE+".txt")         
f= open(FileName, "w") 



def on_release(key):
    
    print("f")
    if str(key) == "'c'":
        print('Copying the slected')
        text = pyperclip.paste()  # text will have the content of clipboard
        print(text)
        text = striprtf(text)
        text = text.replace('\n\n', '\n')
        print(text)
        f.write(text+"\n")

    
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        print("End")
        return False


# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
    
f.close()
```

Comment: I reinstalled Anaconda. No help there. However I managed to get the code working when running it in the terminal, by switching the shebang from #! /usr/bin/env python3 to #! /usr/bin/python3. So problem partially solved.

Comment: The changing of the shebang wasn't the solution. Just checked that it works with both shebangs, but somehow it's now working in the terminal..